# Is :text case sensitive?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is the jQuery :text selector case sensitive?

For Example:

```
<input type="TEXT">
```

Does not match but:

```
<input type="text">
```

Does match.

This appears to be the case.  I'm just looking for verification.

**EDIT**

It is looking like even the [type=text] selector is case sensitive in Chrome and Firefox but not IE8 (in IE8 document mode)

Comment: No it's not `case sensitive` as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RMhK/2/

Comment: `$(':text') is equivalent to $('[type=text]')` (http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/). Doesn't look like: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWfb6/

Comment: @sally First element is **not** matched.. http://jsfiddle.net/6VzNv/

Comment: `$(':text')` you are selecting it as a form element and it will be case sensitive in this case while using `$('[type=text]')` we are selecting it by attribute and that's not `case sensitive`

Comment: @sally Great, so it's the answer to his question :-)

Comment: Don't use `:text`. It is not a standard CSS selector. Use `$('input[type="text"]')` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: despite my research I drew the *completely wrong conclusion* at first. Answer's been updated :O (kudo's go to @ThiagoSantos who had the correct answer from the start :D).

The [jQuery ":text" documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) states:

> Because :text is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.

If you dive into the [source of 1.7.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) it seems this selector is implemented as:

```
text: function( elem ) {
    var attr = elem.getAttribute( "type" ), type = elem.type;
    // IE6 and 7 will map elem.type to 'text' for new HTML5 types (search, etc) 
    // use getAttribute instead to test this case
    return elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input" && "text" === type && ( attr === type || attr === null );
}
```

For `<input type="tEXt" />` the value of `attr` turns out to be "tEXt", which won't match `type`. Much to my own surprise then:

The updated answer should be: **:text is case sensitive**

Comment: Wouldn't elem.getAttribute( "type" ) return "tEXt" in your example in which case it would be case sensitive?

Comment: Aye, I'm sorry. I've updated my answer now. Kudo's go to the other folks who had the correct jsfiddles from the start *hides in shame* :D

Comment: Conclusions are over-rated. ;0)  Actually, if I'm reading the following link correctly, it getAttribute ought to lowercase when the DOM is an HTML doc.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Comment: It lowercases the _argument_ of the getAttribute call, not the return value, no?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is canse sensitive guys.. 
So in reality the following is not true

> $(':text') is equivalent to $('[type=text]')

Here's a sample.. only one alert for this

http://jsfiddle.net/huX3M/

Answer (score 2):

I would say, firstly, *yes* it is case-sensitive.  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj2qe/).

Given that `<input type="text">` should behave *exactly* as `<input type="TEXT">`, I believe this is probably a bug.

In any case, it is better to use `[type="text"]`, since that can be parsed by `querySelectorAll` and will therefore have significant performance benefits.